# Programatically splitting pdf pages to their own pdf's in UNIX

Tags: pdf, split

I am trying to write a program that takes as input a .pdf file and separates each page into their own .pdf files in UNIX command line. I have tried SplitPdf but for some reason I keep getting errors.

update: I have already tried pdftk but it has poor performance and a limitation on the size of the pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

The `burst` command is what you are after.

Man page section: http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-burst

> `burst`
>
> > > Splits a single, input PDF
> > >       document into individual pages. Also
> > >       creates a report named `doc_data.txt`
> > >       which is the same as the output from
> > >       `dump_data`. If the output section is
> > >       omitted, then PDF pages arenamed:
> > >       `pg_%04d.pdf`, e.g.: `pg_0001.pdf`,
> > >       `pg_0002.pdf`, etc. To name these pages
> > >       yourself, supply a printf-styled
> > >       format string in the output section.
> > >       For example, if you want pages named:
> > >       `page_01.pdf`, `page_02.pdf`, etc.,pass
> > >       output `page_%02d.pdf` to pdftk.
> > >
> > > Encryption can be applied to the
> > >       output by appending output options
> > >       such as owner_pw, e.g.: pdftk in.pdf
> > >       burst owner_pw foopass

Comment: How do I install the UNIX version ?

Comment: @twidizle: What *NIX version are you using, it may be available as a package, if not you will need to build it.  See: http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/